# Calculus long division $\int\frac{y^4+3y^2-1}{y^3+3y}\ dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a problem like this in my homework and want to see how to go by doing this problem. I understand the long division, but cannot get the partial fraction part. 
$$\int\frac{y^4+3y^2-1}{y^3+3y}\ dy$$

Comment: As a side note, if you want to double-check your answer (as seen in your comments on lab's answer), [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative+of+%28y%5E4%2B3y%5E2%E2%88%921%29%2Fy%2F%283%2B3y%29) makes this quite simple.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$\frac{y^4+3y^2-1}{y^3+3y}=\frac{y^2(y^2+3)}{y(y^2+3)}-\frac1{y(y^2+3)}$$

$$=y-\frac y{y^2(y^2+3)}$$

For $\displaystyle\frac y{y^2(y^2+3)},$
set $\displaystyle y^2=u$ and then in the numerator  $\displaystyle3=(u+3)-u$

Comment: okay so how do I go about teh next step?

Comment: $$\int\frac y{y^2(y^2+3)}dy=\frac12\int\frac{du}{u(u+3)}=\frac16\int\left(\frac{(u+3)-u}{(u+3)u}\right)du=\cdots$$

Comment: so do I put the y's back i am sorry I am very confused

Comment: @brian, Yes, u have to as this is an indefinite integral

Comment: so i would get ((y^2+3)-y^2)/((y^2+3)y^2)?

Comment: and would the final answer be (y^2)/2-(1/3)ln|y|+(1/6)ln(y^2+3)+C?

Comment: Alternate suggestion for that fraction: multiply top and bottom by $y^{-3}$ instead of $y$ to get $\frac{y^{-3}}{1+3y^{-2}}$, then substitute $u=1+3y^{-2},du=-6y^{-3}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{y^4+3y^2-1}{y^3+3y}=y-\frac{1}{y(y^2+3)}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{y(y^2+3)}=\frac{A}{y}+\frac{By+C}{y^2+3}\ .$$
Multiplying out,
$$1=A(y^2+3)+y(By+C)$$
and equating coefficients gives
$$A+B=0\ ,\quad C=0\ ,\quad 3A=1\ .$$
So
$$\int\frac{y^4+3y^2-1}{y^3+3y}\,dy
  =\int y\,dy-\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{dy}{y}+\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{y}{y^2+3}\,dy$$
and I think you can take it from here.